# conditional selection of items from tables inside R list object

Tags: r, list

I have an R list containing a series of tables.  Each table in the list contains named items and their corresponding values.   I want to iterate over each table of the list and return a count of how many of the items in each of the tables have a `value == 1`.

Assume, for example, the following list:

```
> someitems <- c("the", "cat", "and", "the", "hat")
> someotheritems <- c("it", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times", "it", "was", "the")
> my.list <- list(table(someitems), table(someotheritems))
> my.list

[[1]]
someitems
and cat hat the 
  1   1   1   2 

[[2]]
someotheritems
 best    it    of   the times   was 
    1     2     1     2     1     2
```

I need now to return a count of the items in each table of the list that have a `value == 1`,

e.g. from the above return

```
3
3
```

I can see, how to do this by looping, but how to do it without loops?

I've experimented with `lapply()` and I know how to get at the values using:

```
lapply(my.list, '[')
```

and I have written a custom function for detecting `items == 1`.  e.g.

```
is.one <- function(x) if(x==1) return (TRUE) else return(FALSE)
```

but I'm not quite getting how to combine the two, and there ought to be an easier way than using this silly function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In learning how to do this, it is helpful to work with a single instance and then use `lapply` on an anonymous function that generalizes the method:

```
> my.list[[1]] == 1
someitems
  and   cat   hat   the 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
> sum(my.list[[1]] == 1)
[1] 3
> lapply(my.list, function(x) sum(x == 1)  )
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

If you are expecting the result to be regular then `sapply` can sometimes reduce the returned value to a vector or matrix:

```
sapply(my.list, function(x) sum(x == 1) )
[1] 3 3
```

Comment: I knew it must be simpler than I was making it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr) 
count=ldply(my.list, function(x) length(which(x==1)))
```